# Populate form fields with Django forms after raise validation error

Tags: javascript, django

i need help, im new with django forms o how its work.Have a html form and i encrypted the values with javascript when the form is submited like this

```
$("#form").submit(function(){
    //remplace the original value and send to the server the encrypted data
    $("#field1").val(encrypted_data);
    $("#field2").val(encrypted_data);
return true
});
```

I have this class in my django project

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):

field1 = forms.CharField(label="field 1")
field2 = forms.CharField(label="field 1")

clean_field1(self):
 data = decrypt_text(self.cleaned_data['field1'])
 p = re.compile(r'[\d]{8}')
 #validate decrypt data is a number and his lengt is more than 8
 if p.match(data) is None:
    raise forms.ValidationError("Error")

 return data
```

this work fine, the problem is when the data es invalid, i need pass to the field the original value, and currently returns the field with de encrypted value.

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it: 
In your post() method in the class based view, you will have this condition

```
if form.is_valid():
# you do whatever you want with this form
else:
# when your form raises a validation error, this snippet gets executed 
#so you need to write the following lines in the else condition to 
#repopulate your form:
context['form'] = self.form_class(self.request.POST)
return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Now when you have a validation error, you can see it there in the template as well. 
Hope you found this useful